# Apex Application Item is not maintained across sessions

Tags: oracle-apex

Under Apex 4.2.5
I have created an Application Item with Scope = Application and Session State Restriction = Unrestricted.
I am setting this item using a Computation on page 1 after page submit.
I can see the value after its computation in a text field.

Now I connect with a different browser to the same page.
I was expecting to find the Application Item value in the text filed, but it is not present.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: All variables stores in session. So, if you start new session, all variables will be clear in this new session. If you want save some data between sessions, store it in some table, then show.

Answer (score 2):

As per your explanation it seems like you are connecting to the application via different browser altogether. Can you post the URLs you get from both the browsers?

**Oracle Apex relies heavily on SESSION ID** and if you are connecting to a particular application (specifying the APP_ID) from **different browsers**, you would actually land up having **two different SESSION IDs** [check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm) for more clarity] and thus you would not be able to find the same value in different sessions.